# Sitecore "You must lock this item before you can edit" is missing

Tags: locking, sitecore, workflow, sitecore8

I don't know where to turn on this warning message.
[image]

I tried this option `<setting name="RequireLockBeforeEditing" value="true"/>` but it didn't help me.

Google didn't help me also.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a clean install of Sitecore 8.1, unless you have the correct license that supports Commerce then the editor notifications will be overridden with a warning about this. This will suppress all other notifications, including the Lock & Edit warning.

[image: Commerce Warning]

You can work round the issue by [including this patch](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/852031) (which essentially just removes the Commerce License Editor Warning from `getContentEditorWarnings` pipeline).

```
<getContentEditorWarnings>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.ContentEditorLicenseWarning, Sitecore.Commerce">
        <patch:delete/>
    </processor>
</getContentEditorWarnings>
```

If the setting `RequireLockBeforeEditing = true` you should now see the warning notification about "Lock & Edit".

[image: Notification Warnings]

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it works! I thought that it is may be because of this licence warning, because I saw "lock and edit" on instance of sitecore with correct licence, but I made a wrong conclusion from it :)

Comment: The specific issue is that the `Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.ContentEditorLicenseWarning` sets `contentEditorWarning.IsExclusive = true` and that suppresses all other warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This option is only displayed for non-admin users.

If you are logged in as `admin` or any other user with administrator access rights, you won't see it.

Comment: I tried to login as a content editor and this message didn't show. I have a clean sitecore 8.1 on my local IIS

Comment: This should work OOTB with the setting you mentioned. Can you check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`? Maybe there is some patch file which overrides the value of that setting?

Comment: I tried it too, this config section is here with correct value.